# Iframe form doesn't submit

Tags: html, iframe

I have an Iframe with a form.
On our website it seems to work fine, but when I add this Iframe to a fiddle or to one of my customers website, It seems to not submit the form and also not validate the fields anymore.

The working URL: https://publicanda.dstnydev.nl/anac
The not working URL: https://www.onzeklantenservice.nl/wijziging/test/

The iframe itself:

```
<iframe id="resizeFrame" src="https://verzforms.dstnydev.nl/wijziging-doorgeven/verhuizing-doorgeven" frameborder="0" padding="0" margin="0" width="100%" style="min-height:500px;" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

We don't know what the problem might be, can you help me find the difference why its not working on one site?

Comment: On your working URL, the POST request gets an HTML document as response, with status code 200 OK. On your no-working version, the POST request gets answered with status code 303 See Other (and the `Location` pointing to the same URL), which the browser will then follow by making a GET request - at which point, all POST data is lost. _Why_ your form (or rather, the processing endpoint) reacts this way, can hardly be told from the outside though. Maybe there is some sort of referrer check implemented.